# Dynamically generate iframe and change its CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am generating dynamically iframe  and with the help jquery try to change its css
     var iframeId = "iframe0";
     var iframeIdSelector = "#"+iframeId;

```
  document.getElementById("dialogbox").innerHTML = infoHTML+
  '<iframe id = "'+iframeId+'" seamless src="'+url+'"></iframe>';

  $( '#iframe0' ).contents().find( "body" ).css( "background-color", "blue" );
  // unable to change the css of generated ifame ;
```

Comment: yup url is coming  from db.ifame working proper but can't change css OF it

Comment: because you can't. it's not allowed, unless it's on the same domain.

Comment: :-( now what i can do .Can i check the content its empty or not of Iframe